# Does it seems that my supervisor was reluctant to let me go for conference?

Tags: advisor, conference

I have already finished the first draft of my thesis and now I'm reviewing chapter by chapter. A few days ago I submitted my abstract to a conference and was accepted. I emailed my supervisor and asked for permission to go for conference, but she didn't answer. From my experiences of working with her, she didn't answer means she didn't want to answer and she didn't agree.

I am confused at the moment why it happened like this. She always spoke highly of my work and told me that one of my results chapter can already been made into a journal article. So I'm wondering if I should ask her before submitting my abstract?

Do I have to ask my supervisor first and submit the abstract? Do I include my supervisor's name in the abstract? I'm working in the field of humanities, and I collected and analysed the data, but she involved in the research design in my early stage and now she is giving me feedback on my writing.

So I really want to know if it's just she didn't want me to go for conference or my unethical behaviour offend her? Shall I ask her in the supervisory meeting again for this issue to figure out what's the problem?

Comment: You are asking for an interpretation of an action (actually an inaction) of someone we don't know. You are much better placed to make a guess, but you should really just ask. In person.

Comment: Why do you need anyone's permission to go to a conference?  Just go.

Comment: @JeffE OP needs permission to name her as co-author (supervisor was involved in the work) and didn't ask. Without that, there is no submission and, without submission, likely, no funding.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Sure. But that’s not the same tings as _permission to go to the conference_. Permission does not imply funding. Attendance does not imply speaking.

Comment: @JeffE "Do I have to ask my supervisor first and submit the abstract? Do I include my supervisor's name in the abstract?" - I think it is pretty unambiguous that she wanted not just to go, but to present this work.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs  OP is conflating attendance, presentation, and funding in their question, which strongly suggests that OP is conflating those things in their mind as well.

Answer (score 5):

> she didn't answer means she didn't want to answer and she didn't agree.

She may not have answered for many reasons.

> So I'm wondering if I should ask her before submitting my abstract?
>   Do I have to ask my supervisor first and submit the abstract?

If you want her to fund your attendance, then *yes*.

> Do I include my supervisor's name in the abstract? I'm working in the field of humanities, and I collected and analysed the data, but she involved in the research design in my early stage and now she is giving me feedback on my writing.

It sounds like she's a co-author, so *yes*.

> So I really want to know if it's just she didn't want me to go for conference or my unethical behaviour offend her?

Again, she may not have answered for many reasons, but you require her permission to list her as a co-author and you may require her funds to attend, so you should have probably asked her first.

> Shall I ask her in the supervisory meeting again for this issue to
>   figure out what's the problem?

Yes.

Comment: I don't use her funds cuz the school provides the funds but it requires supervisor's support...

Comment: @superwoman0723 Getting permission for funds is therefore less important and probably depends upon the school. Permission is still necessary to include her name as a co-author